# Is there any Magento configuration generator out there to simplify magento development?

Tags: magento

As you know Magento has a configuration based MVC framework and so it's really based on some .xml files that creating them is time-consuming and boring! Is there any geek out there that developed a tool or website that can simplify this process give some input and provide a snippet?

A tool  or any thing else an IDE for example or a CLI or anything that can simplify generating configuration .xml files can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is general structure and base class generator for modules

http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/#.U2RjpnWSylg